# Select2 plugin and cancellation of selected data

Tags: jquery, select, input

I'm using [Select2 library](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) v3.3, the popular jQuery based replacement for select boxes.

In particular, I'm testing the example with the ajax call to *RottenTomatoes* (see *Loading Remote Data* section [here](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/index.html)). There, an hidden input is put in the HTML code and then the Select2 library is attached to the hidden input to render the "custom select".

To make the example self contained, here I report the code for the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="e6" style="width:600px"/>
```

as well as for for the JS:

```
<script>
    $("#e6").select2({
        placeholder: "Search for a movie",
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
            url: "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    q: term, // search term
                    page_limit: 10,
                    apikey: "ju6z9mjyajq2djue3gbvv26t" // please do not use so this example keeps working
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
                return {results: data.movies};
            }
        },
        formatResult: movieFormatResult, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        formatSelection: movieFormatSelection,  // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
    });

  function movieFormatResult(movie){return movie.title;}
  function movieFormatSelection(movie){return movie.title;}
</script>
```

**Once that a value is selected, how can I erase this value from a jQuery function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines should works:

```
function erase(){
    $("#e6").select2("data", null);
}
```

I know, one would expect that `val` param should be set for this example, but you must use `data` instead.